# CloudpagesURL function does not work if UTM tracking code is added from SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, email-tracking

I am using the CloudpagesURL to populate a page with information in the DE of the email send. The clients BU has UTM tracking enabled which appends UTM tracking to all links on email send.

When directed to the cloudpage the generated key has UTM tracking on it and the data does  not feed through, remove the UTM from the link and it works 100%.

The client doesn't want to remove the UTM for SFMC as it tracks all mails, how would I get around it for this link to work and the data to flow into the cloudpage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000356997&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&language=en_US) with the CloudPagesURL function:

> In your Email you want to redirect a Subscriber to a specific
> CloudPage of your choice after clicking on a Button.
>
> When you configure a Button within your Email, you have the option to
> select the CloudPage directly.  After selecting the CloudPage, the
> Editor will automatically add the CloudPageURL function and PageID of
> the CloudPage.  Subscribers whom receive the Email will see this page
> when they click on the link.
>
> With the Web Analytics Connector (WAC) enabled, Subscribers will click
> the button link and the WAC UTM Parameters will be appended onto the
> URL, prefixed by the ? character in the URL.
>
> Following this process, you will see that the link will error because
> the URL will have two question marks (?), one that is added by the
> CloudPagesURL function and another one that is added by the WAC to
> include all the UTM parameters.

To resolve it, you need to wrap all your CloudPagesURL functions in a [RedirectTo](https://ampscript.guide/redirectto/) function:

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(123))=%%">Click Here< /a>
```

If you’re appending additional parameters to the query string, create a separate variable for the CloudPagesURL function with all additional parameters and pass this variable wrapped in the RedirectTo function in the anchor tag.

Comment: Thank you I will give this a go, we did come up with a solution of adding a & to the end of the link:

<a href="%%=(CloudPagesURL(123))=%%&">Click Here< /a>

Comment: @Factor33 - if this answer helped you, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark - thanks!